# HTTP webserver gateway timeout 504 only from one ISP

Tags: timeout, isp, mtu, 504, centos6.6

I have configured a **nginx http webserver** to serve a site on **CentOS 6** Virtual machine. every things are works fine but when I connect to site from a special ISP, the site wait and after a while respond **504 Gateway timeout**. This occurs only from this ISP not any else.
 After several search I found that this problem may be related to **MTU** of my interface. I changed **MTU** to **1400** but still the problem exist. Can anyone help me?

**Edit**

You can see traffic capture in this image:

[image: packets]

I have changed MTU in server to 1400 but server responses `MSS=1460` that mean MTU is 1500. When I capture traffic and check the **MSS** on other ISPs, I get `MSS=1360` and this is correct.

You can see server packets in this image:

[image]

Comment: Can you provide a traffic capture of the issue? You haven't really provided many details to go on here.

Comment: Thanks alot @MarkoPolo. I have provided additional details.

Comment: Thanks, can you run the capture from both ends - server and client - which should highlight if this is an MTU issue or not.

Comment: As you can see server responses packets with `MTU=1360`.

Comment: Remember that MSS is unidirectional and client and server are free to set whichever MSS they choose. Your server is using an MSS of 1360 because you changed your interface MTU to 1400. The client does not need to use the same MSS.

The server packet capture is showing nothing but retransmissions. The server receives the SYN from the client, sends its SYN/ACK response but then the clients sends another SYN packet. This suggests that the SYN/ACK packets from your server are not actually being received by the client.

Comment: This is OK. the problem is that when I connect from another ISP, it works correctly.

Comment: As this issue only occurs with the one ISP, you should contact them to find out what they are doing to your web traffic.